# How to add languages for localizations IOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode

In info settings my IOS project I try to add languages for localizations app, but see just Chinese, English, French, German, Italian, Japanese and Korean. How to add other languages?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) We can add more languages..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this successfully using other way, dont know if this is helpful for you .

I have created resource file with for desired language . That was basically a JSON file with key as some key and value as its translated version.Then as per the setting fetched the desired json from the resource and rendered the value against key .

Answer (score 0):

Needs select project in Xcode's file navigator, not the target (it is my error), and that the Info panel is highlighted blue.